# PHP unzip file with folders and files international letter

Tags: php, encoding, zip

I compressed folders and files by built-in Windows tool (Context menu: Send to zip file). The folders and files will be prepared by clients. Lots of folders and files can have international letters (like `finanças`, `zapłacone`, `świetnie!` and `straße`).

When I extract folders by PHP ZipArchive class, some of folders has changed names, respectively: `finanças` (correct), `zapêacone` (incorrect), `ÿwietnie!` (incorrect) and  `straße` (correct).

It's strange, I research the Lating charactras and the letters:
`ç` and `ß` are in group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended_Additional
`ł` and `ś` are in group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-A

So, How I can to force it to work better with letter `ł` and `ś`?

I tried with `iconv` and `mb_*` function from PHP, but there is no effect.

Comment: Are you sure the letters change when you extract in php? Maybe they already change when the zip is made?

Comment: @DirkScholten It's make possible

Comment: I have no influence on it